# Write numbers to a file

Tags: output-formatting, output

I want create file with some text (and numbers). This is my code.

```
str=OpenWrite["f:\\1.txt",PageWidth->Infinity, FormatType->StandardForm,NumberMarks->True];
Write[str, "a = ", 0.123456789];
Close[str]
```

The problem is there is rounded number (0.123457) in the output file.
but I actually want file with text

```
a = 0.123456789
```

**Explaining**:
I want parse a test suite files (*.mt) with data for check.
Rows looks like

```
dataAcc = {{1.865987700, 1.920469000, 1.811506300, ...},...}
Get[childTestLocation<>"nameOfChildTest.mt"]
```

I have a numbers for dataAcc list. But when i create testfile numbers becomes rounded.

Comment: Maybe you can specify the precision of `a` using `a = 0.123456789\`9`

Comment: Or if you don't want low precision from definition, but instead prefer crop the precision when output, you can use `a=0.123456789; SetPrecision[a, 9]`. The latter outputs 9 digits.

Comment: It's solve the problem. But interesting is there another way to solve this problem

Comment: another way: `Write[ .. , "a = 0.123456789" ]`.  Seriously you need to explain a little better exactly what you are trying to do,

Comment: If you want to retain precision of arbitrary number, you could wrap it with `FullForm`: `Write[str, "a = ", FullForm[a]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you are after something like:

```
ToString[NumberForm[0.123456789, {∞, 9}]]
```

to explicitly specify the number of decimal places.  For example, using `WriteString` which does the `ToString` bit for you:

```
str = OpenWrite["test.txt"];
WriteString[str, "a = ", NumberForm[0.1234, {∞, 9}], "\n"];
WriteString[str, "b = ", NumberForm[0.123456789, {∞, 9}], "\n"];
Close[str]
```

Which results in:

```
FilePrint["test.txt"]
```

> a = 0.123400000 
>   b = 0.123456789

But really you need to be more specific about what you want as george2079's comment has a solution with a lot less typing and using *Mathematica* as a text editor is not very efficient!